# Run .bat file from a webpage

Tags: html, windows, batch-file

I'm looking to find a way on how to start a .bat file from a webpage. This bat file just start a server.
My intention is to create a basic html page showing "Start server" and "Close Server".
Is there a way to  do so? I was thinking to do it by an FTP server using HTML but it didn't helped me.

Thanks

Comment: Your user will have to execute the batch, this can't be done automatically

Comment: Not possible with basic HTML. HTML is just blindly served by most web servers without executing custom logic. You'd have to use some form of server-side application platform to do this.

Comment: @Marged It is not automatically because on the html page I will create two buttons. One to start the .bat and another way that will call another bat, to close the bat opened.

Comment: @xxbbcc Can you suggest me a way/tutorial to do this?

Comment: @user3285229 HTML (and anything spawned off of it) runs _in the browser_.

Comment: Understood, but all you can do is _provide_ a batch for download. _Then_ the user will have to _execute_ that batch manually.

Comment: Ali created a good question: where is the batch supposed to run ? On the server hosting the batch or on the client ?

Comment: @Marged The batch is needed to start, by my server, a game server. You know that I cannot give the access to join on my server so the best way was to provide them a webpage when by simply clicking start/stop server, everything would have worked.

Comment: You need some sort of server side logic. So a CGI executable or php script or similar that is the target of a form inside the html page.

Comment: You are basically trying to do a server side include.  This is not possible unless you configure your web server to function that way.  I would never in a million years configure my web server to run a batch file.

Comment: @arkascha Basically yes. I'm getting crazy because this has to work from the other PC. So they just access on a basic html page, they click start/stop server and that's all.
Need to find a way on how to create, not the html, but the logic behind

Comment: I did answer that with my last comment. What is unclear about that?

Comment: @arkascha A script or a source to look for

Comment: Well, a script would be trivial, a one liner. But the question is: what type of script does your setup support? What options do you have on the server side? You probably can even use that batch script you have as a cgi executable, I guess, though I have next to no experience with MS-Windows. Yu ahve to configure your http server to offer and execute CGI scripts. Take a look at the documentation of whatever http server you use.

Comment: What do you mean of which options I have on the server side? @arkascha

Comment: Just as mentioned above: CGI execution or php scripting or something similar. What do you use or have setup? I mean _you_ know your environment. We can't tell you how you did setup your system.

Comment: If all this is like some foreign dialect to you then maybe you should start reading some "getting started with web programming" guide or similar. That is nothing we can offer here. This place is to get answers to _specific programming questions_. Don't get that wrong. We all started. It is absolutely fine to be a newbie and to not know ones way at first. But that is something you have to work through. By reading and testing and learning. We cannot magically hand you some script and all is working.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call cgi script for this action with proper access to start your services. Html doesn't have any access in server side. It can only trigger the request.

Put 2 files in your web folder:

1. Static html showing your bottoms
2. A PHP file to call the batch.

Just remember to install PHP on your IIS

Comment: Can you be more explicit? Where can I look for?

Comment: What is your server os? What is your favorite server side programming language?

Comment: Win Server 2012 r2. I do only know php and html...CGI Btw would be better

Answer (score 0):

With a static page would be difficult but for example using `php` :

```
<?php
            exec('c:\myfile.bat');            
    ?>
```

If you don´t want execute the `.bat` locally you will execute a shell script (`.sh`) that executes remotely the batch file.
https://superuser.com/questions/292818/run-a-shell-script-with-an-html-button

Comment: yes, locally it works but how about if I make it running from another pc?

It won't work in this case

Comment: @Elenasts yeah, I know but is less secure sharing them my server password :P

Comment: I had an idea check my answer

Comment: I use windows server, Elenasys

Comment: i tried your code it does not work for me. any other solution ?